# Simple Haskell Factorial Function not compiling

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghci

So I have this simple Haskell function:

```
fact :: (Num a) => a -> a
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n - 1)
```

and when I try to compile it with GHCi, I get an error:

```
test.hs:2:6: error:
    • Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from the literal ‘0’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   fact :: Num a => a -> a
        at test.hs:1:1-25
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            fact :: Num a => a -> a
    • In the pattern: 0
      In an equation for ‘fact’: fact 0 = 1
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Look, I know that better way to write this function exist, but I don't care. I just want to get this function to compile. I can't do that though. It was my impression that if something was a number, it must be an instance of Eq a, and therefore the compiler's suggestion of a possible fix is wrong.

How can I get this code to compile?

Comment: Use the compiler's suggested fix.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that a type that is an instance of `Num` must also be an instance of `Eq` is false. Consider the inferred type for your function:

```
> fact 0 = 1; fact n = n * fact (n - 1)
> :t fact
fact :: (Num t, Eq t) => t -> t
```

To be an instance of `Num`, a type need only define the following functions:

- `(+)`
- `(*)`
- `abs`
- `signum`
- `fromInteger`
- *either* `negate` or `(-)`

Comment: The assumption is true according to Haskell 2010 though. GHC decided to change it a few versions ago.

Comment: Makes sense; the 5 "built-in" types `Word`, `Integer`, `Int`, `Float`, and `Double` that have a `Num` instance all have an `Eq` instance as well, and I can't really think of an example of a type for which you would only want a `Num` instance.

Comment: I'd love to expand my answer, but I can't seem to load haskell.org from my computer, and it appears to be some obscure certificate-expired problem that I can't debug right now. Is there any reason why GHC changed that?